# Java generic parameter method to avoid code duplication

Tags: java, generic-programming, code-reuse

I have a function that parse an object. But this function is required in two services and the parameter have same class name, but different package name. What i need is to avoid duplicated code.

Suppose the function is:

```
    private HashMap<String, Integer> getPagination(PagingRequestType pagingRequestType) {
        int pageSize = 200;
        int pageNumber = 1;
        if(pagingRequestType != null) {
            if (pagingRequestType.getNumberOfRecordsPerPage() != 0) {
                pageSize = pagingRequestType.getNumberOfRecordsPerPage();
            }
            if (pagingRequestType.getStartAtRecordNumber() != 0) {
                pageNumber = pagingRequestType.getStartAtRecordNumber();
            }
        }
        HashMap<String, Integer> result = new HashMap<>();
        result.put("pageNumber", pageNumber);
        result.put("pageSize", pageSize);
        return result;
    }
```

Possible function calls:

```
- getPagination(new Abc.PagingRequestType());
- getPagination(new Xyz.PagingRequestType());
```

**`PagingRequestType` is an auto-generated class in two different    packages. The function needs to be implemented once and used in both    services.**

Thanks.

Comment: Wait, so do you have two different classes called `PagingRequestType`? That just screams to be fixed, especially if the two implementations are used the same.

Comment: The obvious answer is not to auto-generate `PagingRequestType` in two places.

Comment: Or if that is not avoidable have both PagingRequestType classes implement  a common interface that can then be used in this method.

Comment: Yes, this is not because the classes have the same name, that you can do some generic stuff on it.

Comment: There are two different WSDL files to support legacy system.

Comment: "Possible function calls" How about replacing the `getPagination(new Xyz.PagingRequestType());` with `getPagination(new Abc.PagingRequestType());`?

Comment: Well this is not in my control.

Comment: Hang on a sec: this method isn't actually the issue. If you've got a reference to a `PagingRequestType`, it's one or the other, but not both. You need to make the code *calling* this method generic first.

Answer (score 1):

If you can modify your `PagingRequestType` classes, it will be a good idea to use a common interface:

```
class Abc.PagingRequestType implements PagingRequestType
class Xyz.PagingRequestType implements PagingRequestType

interface PagingRequestType {
    getNumberOfRecordsPerPage();
    getStartAtRecordNumber();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The obvious answer is not to auto-generate `PagingRequestType` in two places.

If you can't do this, you need the two classes to implement a common interface, through which the requisite fields (`getNumberOfRecordsPerPage` and `getStartAtRecordNumber`) are available.

If you can't change the classes, you can create an interface with these fields:

```
interface YourInterface {
  int getNumberOfRecordsPerPage();
  int getStartAtRecordNumber();
}
```

and implement for the two `PagingRequestType`s:

```
class AbcYourInterface implements YourInterface {
  final Abc.PagingRequestType delegate;  // Set in constructor.

  @Override public int getNumberOfRecordsPerPage() {
   return delegate.getNumberOfRecordsPerPage();
  }

  // Same for other method.
}
```

If all else fails, pass in the class fields as separate parameters:

```
private HashMap<String, Integer> getPagination(int numberOfRecordsPerPage, int startAtRecordNumber) {
```

using some "special" value to indicate `null`, e.g. 0, since the conditional is a no-op if both parameters are zero.

Comment: offtopic: is there a specific reason why you deleted your answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43141138/disable-thread-sleep/43141182#43141182 ? I was about to upvote it, when I saw that you already deleted it yourself ?!

Answer (score 0):

Both PagingRequestType could implement one common interface or extend one common class and you could take this "common part" as argument to your function. Although I don't know if you can modify your auto generated code in that way.

Comment: that's the problem on my side @LLL i can't modify WSDL file.

Comment: Then you could use reflection API but it could be overkill

Answer (score 0):

If the option to make those two `PagingRequestType`s to implement a common interface is impossiable, you could do it the reverse way, define a `proxy` type to wrap those two types:

```
public final class PagingRequestTypeProxy {
    private a.b.c.PagingRequestType abcPagingRequestType;

    private a.b.d.PagingRequestType abdPagingRequestType;

    public PagingRequestTypeProxy(PagingRequestType abcPagingRequestType) {
        this.abcPagingRequestType = abcPagingRequestType;
    }

    public PagingRequestTypeProxy(a.b.d.PagingRequestType abdPagingRequestType) {
        this.abdPagingRequestType = abdPagingRequestType;
    }

    public int getNumberOfRecordsPerPage() {
        return abcPagingRequestType != null ? abcPagingRequestType.getNumberOfRecordsPerPage() : abdPagingRequestType.getNumberOfRecordsPerPage();
    }

    public int getStartAtRecordNumber() {
        return abcPagingRequestType != null ? abcPagingRequestType.getStartAtRecordNumber() : abdPagingRequestType.getStartAtRecordNumber();
    }
}
```

And change the parameter type of `getPagination` to:

```
private HashMap<String, Integer> getPagination(PagingRequestTypeProxy pagingRequestType) {...}
```

Then you could use it like:

```
getPagination(new PagingRequestTypeProxy(abcPagingReqType));
getPagination(new PagingRequestTypeProxy(abdPagingReqType));
```

The cons is that there're extra codes to define `PagingRequestTypeProxy`, the pros is that `logic` of `PagingRequestTypeProxy` is very simple and easy to maintain, and you can put your biz code `getPagination` in one place.