# Disable Thread.sleep()

Tags: java

I want to disable possibility of using Thread.sleep() in a java project and use my own method instead:

```
sleep(int time, String info)
```

That will wait for given amount of time, and print info why is waiting necessary here.

Is disabling `Thread.sleep()` possible?

If yes, what's best method to do so?

Comment: Is the problem that you have too many occurances of Thread.sleep() to change them all?

Comment: Well, we WILL have to change them all, but i have to be sure that no one will use Thread.sleep() after it. (test purposes)

Comment: You can't be sure of that. One solution would be to have a rule in a code analyzer (like Sonar) to raise a flag on each occurrence of `Thread.sleep()`

Comment: Your only solution is to write a program that scans your source code for occurances of `Thread.sleep()`.  (If you then link it to `git`, you can maybe send an email to the programmer who wrote then line, :) )

Comment: You don't need to scan code, or analyze source, or what else. IMHO AOP is the right answer, so you can control all accesses made to Thread.sleep() at runtime, and - eventually - disable it when invoked somewhere (or throw an exception, or log it in order to modify code later, etc).

Comment: Hint: read about how to do use our **markdown** editing stuff properly - you dont use HTML tags. You see, all that help text around the edit window exists for a reason ;-) ... and dont forget to accept the most helpful answer at some point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best method would be to have hook on some static code analysis tool to mark build as failed if there are any invocations of `Thread.Sleep()`.

You could probably configure [SonarCube](https://www.sonarqube.org/) to do this.

Answer (score 3):

You can use AOP to intercept calls to Thread.sleep() and "redirect" call to your one via aroundAdvice. When original Thread.sleep() is invoked, a "default cause" is added. This one shows an example about how you can use it (remember to create a AspectJ project, or Aspects will not work):

*SleepAspect.java*

```
package org.norsam.so.sleep

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;

@Aspect
public class SleepAspect
{
    @Around("call (* java.lang.Thread.sleep(..) )")
    public Object aroundAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint point) throws Throwable
    {
        StackTraceElement ste = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2];
        Long ms = (Long) point.getArgs()[0];
        String m = ste.getMethodName();
        String c = ste.getClassName();
        String skip = SleepClass.class.getName();
        if (c.equals(skip) && m.equals("sleep")) {
            System.out.println("sleep well for " + ms + "ms!");
        } else {
            SleepClass.sleep(ms, "Thread.sleep invoked in " + c + "." + m + ", no cause present!");
        }
        Object toret = point.proceed();
        return toret;
    }

}
```

*SleepClass.java*

```
package org.norsam.so.sleep

public class SleepClass {

    public static void sleep(long l, String cause) {
        System.out.println("CAUSE: " + cause);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(l);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        SleepClass.sleep(1000, "I love to sleep 1000");
        Thread.sleep(2000L);
        System.out.println("Bye");
    }

}
```

When you run it, you receive something like

```
CAUSE: I love to sleep 1000
sleep well for 1000ms!
CAUSE: Thread.sleep invoked in org.norsam.so.sleep.SleepClass.main, no cause present!
sleep well for 2000ms!
Bye
```

Comment: PS: Obviously, you can choose to throw an exception instead to print a default message on Thread.sleep() invocations outside your custom sleep method... :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, sure.

Just make sure that no code in that project is calling `Thread.sleep()`; but your `MyUtility.sleep()` replacement.

If the question is: can I *somehow* change the behavior of the existing Thread.sleep(), then the answer is: **depends** on context/effort you are willing to spend.

Well, with certain tricks; it *might* be possible; but simply speaking: it is a most likely a bad idea; and not worth following up on. I would really shy away from changing the code behavior, if at all I would look into those solutions that can identify usages of that unwanted sleep calls at compile time.

Comment: Well, even if Thread.sleep() can't be changed, surely can be controller: IMHO Aspects aren't a "dirty trick", so I don't think that "no" could be the right answer, maybe "complicated" is more appropriate... :) Then I added a quick&dirty working example using AOP.

Comment: You are probably right, I tried to reword my answer accordingly.